# Difference behavior of PHP to show xml

Tags: php, xml

This is my php code.

[xmltest.php]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
  <date>test data</date>
</results>
```

When I run it in tow servers each results are different.

Results in browser from server1 and server2 are here.

[server1]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<results>
<date>test data</date>
 </results>
```

[server2]

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /opt/apache-httpd-2.2.22/htdocs_demo/xmltest.php on line 1
```

I want to fix the problem in server2.

Which settings do I have to check?

Server1 is Windows7(64bit)+Apache2.2.17(32bit)+PHP5.3.14(32bit)

Server2 is CentOS6.4(64bit)+Apache2.2.22(64bit)+PHP5.3.14(64bit)

Comment: There is no reason to have `<?php ?>`. It does nothing.

Comment: I know it now I've removed it.And stil error happens

Comment: I don't know why Server 2 is displaying an error. I would think that xml should be displayed as plain text (xml).

Comment: That t_string error seems like there must be a misused string in htdocs_demo folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your “second server” has [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) enabled, which makes it think `<?` opens a PHP block, and after that it finds `xml`, which is not a valid PHP expression.

Either disable it, or output `<?xml` via PHP in the first place to avoid this.

Comment: I've wrote above comment even if I place `<?xml` in the first line error occures.I edited question text.

Comment: It has absolutely nothing to do with whether it’s one the first line, the third or the fivethousandsevenhundredtwentysecond …

Comment: I can't uderstand what `the third or the fivethousandsevenhundredtwentysecond` is.What does it mean?

Comment: The first _line_, or the third _line_, or the fivethousandsevenhundredtwentysecond _line_ … you said the error still occurs after you moved it to the first line – and I told you that _of course_ it does, because the line number _does not matter at all_. The fact that you are using `<?xml` _is_ causing the problem here, which line it is on is totally irrelevant.

Comment: I set `short_open_tag = Off` in php.ini and problem is fixed.